# !!! CustomerError: Missing frontend definition in buildspec

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error when I try to build the app in aws.

this is the amplify.yml

```
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: "app"
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm --prefix app run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

can anyone help me to solve this error?

I have tried a lot of things but didn't work. It shows me the error again and again.

Comment: the error i am getting is 
!!! CustomerError: Missing frontend definition in buildspec